# pgadmin csrf token missing

Tags: docker, pgadmin

I am running postgres and pgadmin using docker.

Issue is: when I click on logout button (Although, I am able to logout and redirected to login page). But on terminal, I am getting error which is not constant sometimes it is

1. ERROR pgadmin: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
2. ERROR pgadmin: The CSRF token do not match.

And after logout, repeating same process again (login, connect to existing server, then logout) gives same error.

Also, I tried using different pgadmin images but getting same error.

Running as http://localhost:8082/pgadmin4 in browser.
Below is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
        
  db:
    container_name: my_database
    image: postgres:14
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - internal_network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=some_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=some_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=some_db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_DIALECT=postgresql
      - POSTGRES_DRIVER=psycopg2

  pgadmin:
    container_name: my_pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.14
    ports:
     - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - internal_network
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=some_email
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=some_password
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8082
      - SCRIPT_NAME=/pgadmin4
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='None'
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=False
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION=False
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - "db:pg_server"

networks:
  internal_network:
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in the following issue  https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5432 setting the following environment variable solved it:

```
PGADMIN_CONFIG_WTF_CSRF_ENABLED=False
```